# LinQ to SQL naming DataContext

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have created a dbml file which has a DataContext. The dbml maps some of my Database tables.
So far it works good but since I mapped a german database the naming looks quite weird.

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Warengruppe> Warengruppes
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetTable<Warengruppe>();
    }
}
```

For all non German speakers/writers, its like you would read **waregroupens** instead of **waregroups**. Is there a way to adjust the naming of the members in the DataContext ? The DataContext is a generated class and I don't want to adjust this by hand everytime, so I hoped I could set it in the designer and it will apply the naming every time something is changed.

My DataContext is internal and it will be wrapped either way but it looks a little bit like someone hasn't put enough energy into the source code or like he wouldn't care and in this case its me and I don't like that feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off the "Plural"-Naming behavior.
Navigate to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Database Tools` -> `O/R Designer` and turn off the `Pluralization of names` by setting it to `false`.

I think it is not possible to change the plural caption behavior in a way to fit for a defined language. Just on/off is possible. Maybe depends on your VS-Version - in my case VS2013 - its not possible...

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to better understand.

[image]

Comment: this isn't helping at all ;) Its like showing a hungry person your empty hands and telling him this will feed you.

Comment: No its more like... if a friend asks you if you know how to dance and you say: "of course let me show you how" ... and then you do nothing

Comment: The answer referenced an image but didn't actually show it. How's this @Bongo?